# Is there any way to inspect kernel space in GDB?

Tags: memory, x86, kernel

I may have a more fundamental misunderstanding here, so I will outline everything:

I wanted to gain a better understanding of how programs are laid out in memory. Starting from [here](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/anatomy-of-a-program-in-memory/) I went and made some simple programs and opened them up in GDB to see where things were laid in a more practical sense:

```
0x0 - 0x08048000 = ??
0x08048000 = Start .text section
0x08048000 = PLT
0x08048300 = _start
0x08048400 = main
0x08048480 = other functions
0x0804a000 = GOT
0x0804a020 = Start .data section
0x0804a028 = Start .bss section
(random offset)
0x0804b008 = Start heap
...
0xf7?????? = Start memory mapping section
0xf7e50000 = #included library function definitions
0xf7ff0000 = Linux dynamic loader
(random offset)
0xffffd010 = Top of stack (grows negatively)
(random offset)
```

I understand that a lot of these addresses are subject to change, but it helped me visualize it by assigning numbers to things.

Anyway, in the following picture presented in the source above, there's a block dedicated to the Kernel space at the top of the program address space:

[image: Memory Layout]

But a whole gigabyte is allowed for it! The top of the stack in the program I examined was at 0xffffd010, leaving very little space for kernel-related things afterwards. Is it really all there? Does it ever grow, pushing the rest of the program segments closer together in the virtual address space? More importantly, how can I examine it and play with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The top of the stack in the program I examined was at 0xffffd010, leaving very little space for kernel-related things afterwards. Is it really all there?

Your stack is at the top of memory — there's no kernel mapping. That suggests that one of the following is the case:

- You're running a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system, so the kernel is way off in 64-bit space where you can't see it.
- You're running a weird kernel with [the 4GB/4GB patch](http://lwn.net/Articles/39283/) applied, so the kernel is (again) in a totally separate address space
- You're on a non-x86 architecture that *always* has separate address spaces for user and system processes (like PowerPC, I believe?)

To get a look at what your address space *actually* looks like, take a look at `/proc/$pid/maps` for your process while it's running.

> Does it ever grow, pushing the rest of the program segments closer together in the virtual address space?

No. The size of the kernel mapping is compiled into the kernel, and never changes at runtime. (It can be configured to be 2GB/2GB instead of 3GB/1GB, but that's very uncommon.)

> More importantly, how can I examine it and play with it?

You can't — at least, not from user space. That's where the kernel lives.

Comment: Your first guess was completely correct. I'm running a program on 64-bit Ubuntu which was compiled using the -m32 flag. Thank you!